# Will MO have Community Promotion Ads?

Tags: discussion

[Community Promotion Ads](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/) seem to be a useful tool for helping spread various links that might be useful for users of the site.

I have mostly encountered them at [MSE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads). I have learned several interesting things from them and I consider them useful. I do not know much about usage of them on other sites in SE network.

Do we want them here at MO, too? (On MSE, the questions for posting community ads were created by a member of SE team. So I suppose that, if we want to use them here, we need to ask SE team to start such a thread on this meta, too.)

Comment: I feel that this has been discussed on tea, but I can't find a link.

Comment: Google returns some results for [community promotion ads site:tea.mathoverflow.net](http://www.google.com/search?q=community+promotion+ads+site%3Atea.mathoverflow.net). Searching for [community ads site:tea.mathoverflow.net](http://www.google.com/search?q=community+ads+site%3Atea.mathoverflow.net) gives more results, although some of them seem to be completely unrelated. I am not sure whether some of them might be what you had in mind.

Comment: IIRC, the wish expressed in old discussion was rather "no ads" (personally I have not strong feelings regarding this though). I also think that for MO it will be harder to find ads that are perceived as interesting and not just as ads.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly - these ads are not paid by outside companies, but are freely distributed on behalf of non-profit organizations?

Comment: @S.Carnahan Yes, you can advertise the arXive, nLab, or something like that.

Comment: @S.Carnahan In short, the way this works is that we (SE) set up a thread here on meta where the community on MO can suggest and vote on ads that would be displayed on the main site. This is entirely community-driven, no money is involved, and it's pretty much entirely automated based on the votes in that thread. Here's an example - the currently active thread on Ask Ubuntu - http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5504/community-promotion-ads-2013. When someone posts a new ad as an answer, it's not added into the rotation until it gets at least 6 votes from other community members.

Comment: To give one example which might be interesting for MO users, JDH used Community Promotion Ads to promote Cantor's Attic, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3425/8297).

Comment: Can we please revisit this discussion and start the process for ads?

Comment: afaik _every_ SE site has these community ads at least possible. dont know history of why this site does not, maybe it was part of the negotiation of bringing it back into the SE network, wish someone in the know would explain that. for those not aware, the "community ads" are for anything and are voted on by the community. the [physics.se](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7426/community-promotion-ads-2016) site for example has a lot of great ads and shows that they dont degrade the site at all but add to it. in theory even stuff like very popular math blogs could be in ads etc

Comment: I agree with @MartinSchröder , we should have Community Promotion Ads here like we do on the other SE sites!